# Getting error while calling Unity Web Request the payload is displaying in the Unity Editor Console but Empty in WebGL Chrome Console

Tags: unity-game-engine, openai-api, unity-webgl, chatgpt-api

I am calling OpenAI APIs but receiving an error of "Provide Model Parameter"
It is working fine in the Editor but not in WebGL

```
        private async void DispatchRequest<T>(string path, string method, Action<List<T>> onResponse, Action onComplete, CancellationTokenSource token, byte[] payload = null) where T: IResponse
        {
            string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(payload);
            Debug.Log(result);

            using (var request = UnityWebRequest.Post(path, result))
            {
                request.method = method;
                request.SetHeaders(Configuration, ContentType.ApplicationJson);

                var asyncOperation = request.SendWebRequest();
            }
       }
```

Debug.Log(result) is loaded in Editer but empty in Chrome I am passing OpenAI Chat Completion parameters

Comment: depends where and what - there was a unity ad lot who strongly advertised how great they were and supported webgl, except, they hadnt sorted cors on their website and it blocked it working - does your browser console show any cors issues?

Comment: Yes, It was showing but I overcome that.

Comment: whats showing? your unity app? thats not the same...

Comment: are you checking the result codes? as you dont show the what happens on download completion - cors would also explain why its not working..